# Fallo sintaxis MySQL. Procedure, Insert, call

Tags: mysql, sql

**No encuentro fallo de sintaxis**

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE
        pAddTwoProjects (userId_P1 INT , nameP1 VARCHAR, amountP1 INT, yearP1 INT,
                            userId_P2 INT, nameP2 VARCHAR, amountP2 INT, yearP2 INT)
BEGIN
        INSERT INTO projects (idUser, projectName, budget, projectYear) VALUES (userId_P1 , nameP1 , amountP1 , yearP1 );
        INSERT INTO projects (idUser, projectName, budget, projectYear) VALUES (userId_P2 , nameP2 , amountP2 , yearP2 );
END //      
DELIMITER ;

CALL pAddTwoProjects(1, “Proyecto Albatros”, 10000, 2022,
                            2, “Proyecto Búho”, 10000, 2023)
```

[image: DATOS USUARIO]

[image: Procedure]

Answer (score 0):

El problema era muy tonto, se me olvidó poner `VARCHAR(100)` y que tengo que usar `''` (comillas simples) en vez de `""`(comillas dobles).

:)

Comment: Excelente! te recomiendo aceptar tu propia respuesta :)